# How to check if cursor exists (open status)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I check if a cursor is open or not? Because many times I am encountering the error 'Cursor already exists'. Please let me know how can I check whether a cursor is already in open status.

In fact I have closed as well as Deallocated it at the end (CLOSE ppm_cursor; DEALLOCATE ppm_cursor;) But Still i am getting the same error what could be the reason.

Comment: "How can i ensure whether a cursor is not already in open status."  Perhaps you should **not** be doing this.  Generally, you should close every cursor every time you finish with it.  You should never find a cursor left open.

Comment: .... or avoid cursors in the first place! ....

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: @s.Lott I have closed as well as Deallocated it at the end of file (CLOSE ppm_cursor; DEALLOCATE ppm_cursor;) But Still i am getting the same error what could be the reson.

Comment: the error 'Cursor already exists' means that "I have closed as well as Deallocated it at the end of file" is wrong.  You need to close **as soon as possible**.  You need to write a TINY sample program which shows the error.  And post the TINY sample program with the error message.  The **smallest** program you can write which gives the error.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use the [CURSOR_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177609.aspx) function to determine its state.

```
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','myCursor')>=-1
BEGIN
 DEALLOCATE myCursor
END
```

Comment: For anyone else trying this with a cursor you yourself opened, and is maybe is left allocated because of error handling, you may have to change the `global` part to `local`. Curse of the infamous SO copy/paste :-P

Answer (score 51):

Close the cursor, if it is empty then deallocate it:

```
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','myCursor') >= -1
 BEGIN
  IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','myCursor') > -1
   BEGIN
    CLOSE myCursor
   END
 DEALLOCATE myCursor
END
```

Comment: Good, but maybe consider adding a begin/end around the inner IF to avoid confusion about your intent.  My first thought was you had forgotten one, then remembered SQL also doesn't require it for single lines... just a little confusion avoided

Comment: Is it possible for the results of the two cursor status' to be different?

Comment: Just to add: if you use the cursor stored in local variable declared somewhere in the script (e.g. DECLARE @cursorName CURSOR ) use appropriate cursor type ('variable') when getting status: CURSOR_STATUS('variable','@cursorName').

Comment: deallocating a cursor automatically closes it.

Answer (score 7):

Just Small change to what Gary W mentioned, adding 'SELECT':

```
IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','myCursor')) >= -1
BEGIN
 DEALLOCATE myCursor
END
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/eb268010-75fd-4c04-9fe8-0bc33ccf9357

Comment: Should be

`IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','myCursor')) >= -1`

Note the position of the first open bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a previous answer, this proc is useful to call if you are worried that the cursor may have been left open or allocated

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CloseAndDeallocateCursor
    @cursorName NVARCHAR(80)
AS
BEGIN
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global', @cursorName) >= -1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(91)
        IF CURSOR_STATUS('global', @cursorName) > -1
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = N'CLOSE ' + @cursorName
            EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL
        END
        SET @SQL = N'DEALLOCATE ' + @cursorName
        EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL
    END
END
GO
```

... and then sample usage ...

```
EXEC dbo.CloseAndDeallocateCursor 'myCursor'
DECLARE myCursor STATIC 
        FOR SELECT * FROM blah
```

Comment: *"Expanding on a previous answer"* Which answer? There are several other answers here.

Comment: Sorry, @prateek's ... I just turned it into a procedure you can call safely before trying to open it yourself, or for that matter close even if it might be already closed ...

Answer (score 0):

I rarely employ cursors, but I just discovered one other item that can bite you here, the scope of the cursor name.

If the database CURSOR_DEFAULT is global, you will get the "cursor already exists" error if you declare a cursor in a stored procedure with a particular name (eg "cur"), and while that cursor is open you call another stored procedure which declares and opens a cursor with the same name (eg "cur").  The error will occur in the nested stored procedure when it attempts to open "cur".

Run this bit of sql to see your CURSOR_DEFAULT:

```
select is_local_cursor_default from sys.databases where name = '[your database name]'
```

If this value is "0" then how you name your nested cursor matters!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when a stored procedure running in SSMS encountered an error  during the loop, while the cursor was in use to iterate over records and before the it was closed.  To fix it I added extra code in the CATCH block to close the cursor if it is still open (using CURSOR_STATUS as other answers here suggest).